# get the nearest date closest to temp date

Tags: java, date, filter

I have two date fields:

start date `(2021-03-07T07:37:15)` and end date `(2021-03-07T07:37:25)` and temp date `(2021-03-07T07:37:20)` .

I have a list where I have returned 6 records between the start date and end date. How can I filter the records and return the datetime which is closest to temp date?

here in the example records I need to get the 2nd record because the `2021-03-07T07:37:19.999` is closet to the temp date.
Example

```
    2021-03-07T07:37:15.000
    2021-03-07T07:37:19.999
    2021-03-07T07:37:20.000
    2021-03-07T07:37:20.809
    2021-03-07T07:37:22.100
    2021-03-07T07:37:22.814
```

```
     public RequiredRecord findCloseRecord(List<RequiredRecord > list,  Date tempDate) {
Date startTime  = new Date(tempDate.getTime() - 5000);  
    Date endTime = new Date(tempDate.getTime() + 5000);
          Log.logInfo(this, "Find close record");
          if (list != null && !list.isEmpty()) {
               List<RequiredRecord > filteredRec = list.stream()
                         .filter(rec -> (rec.getLogRecDateTime() != null ))
                         .sorted(Comparator.comparing(RequiredRecord ::getLogRecDateTime))
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());    
          
               if (!ClrUtils.isCollectionEmpty(filteredRec)) {
                    return (RequiredRecord ) (filteredRec);
               }
          }
          return null;
     }
```

Comment: where are these `startDate`, `endDate` and `tempDate`?

Comment: the startDate and endDate are +/- 5 seconds from temp date

Comment: and where is `tempDate`?

Comment: the question is not clear and missing details.

Comment: sry tempDate is what i am passing through its - 2021-03-07T07:37:20

Comment: Why is '2021-03-07T07:37:14.000' closest to tempdate? It is actually the furthest from tempdate `2021-03-07T07:37:20`. Also the values are not between start date and end date like you claim

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `ZonedDateTime` or `LocalDateTime`. Both are from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). And then use `Duration.between()` and `Duration.abs()` for finding the unsigned difference from temp date, and find the minimum such difference.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

Use `LocalDateTime`, not `Date`.

Get the closest value(s) by sorting on the absolute value of he distance in time determined by `Duration` class.

```java
Comparator.comparing( ( LocalDateTime ldt ) -> Duration.between( ldt , target ).abs() )
```

## Details

As wisely [commented by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71440453/get-the-nearest-date-closest-to-temp-date#comment126273827_71440453), avoid `Date` class. Along with `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`, and such, these terrible classes were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined by JSR 310.

Create our sample data. [Parse](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#parse(java.lang.CharSequence)) the string inputs as [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) objects.

```java
List < LocalDateTime > ldts =
        List.of(
                LocalDateTime.parse( "2021-03-07T07:00:00.000" ) ,
                LocalDateTime.parse( "2021-03-07T07:37:15.000" ) ,
                LocalDateTime.parse( "2021-03-07T07:37:19.999" ) ,
                LocalDateTime.parse( "2021-03-07T07:37:20.000" ) ,
                LocalDateTime.parse( "2021-03-07T07:37:20.809" ) ,
                LocalDateTime.parse( "2021-03-07T07:37:22.100" ) ,
                LocalDateTime.parse( "2021-03-07T07:37:22.814" ) ,
                LocalDateTime.parse( "2021-03-07T17:00:00.000" )
        );
```

Define our target, what you called your "temp date". I will call it `target`.

```java
LocalDateTime target = LocalDateTime.parse( "2021-03-07T07:37:20" );
```

[In a Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71440453/get-the-nearest-date-closest-to-temp-date#comment126272802_71440453), you said you wanted to filter +/- five seconds.

```java
LocalDateTime tooEarly = target.minusSeconds( 5 );
LocalDateTime tooLate = target.plusSeconds( 5 );
```

Make a [stream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html) of our [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) objects. Filter for outside our five second range, too early or too late. Then filter out any elements that exactly equal our target, as I surmise from your Question though that requirement is not explicitly stated.

Then we ask the stream to [sort](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#sorted(java.util.Comparator)) its remaining elements, using two criteria.

Our first criterion is the absolute value of the distance in time from our target. The absolute part is because we are willing to consider elements that are on either side of the timeline, earlier or later. This approach of using [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) [absolute](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html#abs()) value comes from that same [Comment by Ole V.V.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71440453/get-the-nearest-date-closest-to-temp-date/71462401#comment126273827_71440453)

Our second criterion for sorting is the natural order. I chose this is an arbitrary way to resolve the possibility of two elements being equidistant in time, one ahead and one behind. I chose to go with the earlier one, though you could easily change that.

Lastly we return the very [first item](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst()) of the final sorted stream. The return value is an [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html), as there may be nothing to return depending on the data set.

```java
Optional < LocalDateTime > hit =
        ldts
                .stream()
                .filter( ldt -> ( ! ldt.isBefore( tooEarly ) ) && ldt.isBefore( tooLate ) )
                .filter( ldt -> ( ! ldt.isEqual( target ) ) )
                .sorted(
                        Comparator
                                .comparing(
                                        Function.identity() ,
                                        Comparator.comparing( ( LocalDateTime ldt ) -> Duration.between( ldt , target ).abs() )
                                )
                                .thenComparing( Comparator.naturalOrder() )  // If two elements are equidistant in time (before and after target), go with earlier one as our arbitrary resolution rule.
                )
                .findFirst();
```

Dump to console.

```java
System.out.println( "ldts = " + ldts );
System.out.println( "hit = " + hit );
```

> ldts = [2021-03-07T07:00, 2021-03-07T07:37:15, 2021-03-07T07:37:19.999, 2021-03-07T07:37:20, 2021-03-07T07:37:20.809, 2021-03-07T07:37:22.100, 2021-03-07T07:37:22.814, 2021-03-07T17:00]
>
> hit = Optional[2021-03-07T07:37:19.999]

Comment: thank you for the ans and in the similar way how to achieve in the same code  to get   --- "2021-03-07T07:37:20.809" as it falls in the same second as Temp date? eventhough  2021-03-07T07:37:19.999 is closest .

Comment: @srtummred I am not sure what you are asking in the Comment. Your Question seemed to have ask for the closest date-time that is not the same. That would be 2021-03-07T07:37:19.999.

Comment: yes my initial question was to get the closest . but when there is data at the same second as the Target date , i want to retrive that ,insted of getting the closest. if there is no data at the same second i want to retrive the closest

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the comparator to compare the absolute difference of the date in question and temp date.

```
public RequiredRecord findCloseRecord(List<RequiredRecord> list, Date tempDate) {
        if (list == null || list.isEmpty()) return null;
        
        return list.stream()
                .min(Comparator.comparingLong(d -> Math.abs(tempDate.getTime() - d.getLogRecDateTime().getTime())))
                .orElse(null);
}
```

I'm not sure what logic you need for start and end date. But I suppose you can alter the logic according to your requirement.